# Изменить все border-color и background определенного цвета у разных элементов

Tags: javascript, css, background, border

День добрый.
Возможно ли перебрать все элементы из таблицы стилей с определенными значениями цвета `border-color = #XXXXXX` и `background = #XXXXXX`, и разом заменить им на цвет `#YYYYYY`

Comment: Покажите пример

Comment: Добро пожаловать на форму, будьте любезные добавить ваш код, что бы найти ответ на ваш вопрос быстрее.

Comment: Первое, что приходит на ум это перебрать вообще все элементы через getComputedStyle(ваш_элемент_дом), но это очень ресурсоемкая штука получится. Второе, что приходит на ум это css переменные. Исходя из вашего вопроса это именно то, что вам нужно + это гораздо быстрее и производительнее.

Comment: Можете использовать css переменные.

Comment: В подавляющем большинстве текстовых редакторов есть функция "Найти и заменить", чем она не устраивает?

Answer (score 2):

Тут есть важный момент. Обрати внимание в каком формате возвращаются данные, что бы их сравнивать.

К примеру:

```js
const allBlocks = document.body.querySelectorAll('*');

console.log(getComputedStyle(allBlocks[0]).getPropertyValue('background-color'), ' -- background-color')

console.log(getComputedStyle(allBlocks[0]).getPropertyValue('color'), ' -- color')

console.log(getComputedStyle(allBlocks[0]).getPropertyValue('border-color'), ' -- border-color')
```

```css
div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 150, 2, .1);
  color: red;
  border: 5px solid;
  border-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div>div</div>
```

Вариант готового примера:

```js
const allBlocks = document.body.querySelectorAll('*');
for (let i = 0; i < allBlocks.length; i++) {
  if ((getComputedStyle(allBlocks[i]).getPropertyValue('background-color') == 'rgb(255, 150, 2)')) {
    allBlocks[i].style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(70,40,255)';
  }
  if ((getComputedStyle(allBlocks[i]).getPropertyValue('border-color') == 'rgb(204, 250, 51)')) {
    allBlocks[i].style.borderColor = 'rgb(77,77,77)';
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  background-color: rgb(255, 150, 2);
  border: 5px solid;
  border-color: rgb(204, 250, 51);
}

div:nth-child(2),
div:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 2);
  border: 5px solid;
  border-color: rgb(0, 250, 51);
}

div:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: rgb(255, 250, 2);
}
```

```html
<div>div</div>
<div>div</div>
<div>div</div>
<div>div</div>
<div>div</div>
```